# VS 2017 missing template Blank app (Android) c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to add new project **Blank App (Android) C#** to my solution but only found **Blank app (Android) F#**.

I was looking online templates but nothing.

How to get this template?

or

What else other **C#** template match with my needs ?

Comment: It's there and it doesn't need any special installing. Be sure to install xamarin correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Select the "Android App (Xamarin)" entry for C#:

[image: Project choose]

Then you will get this dialog:

[image: dialog]

There you can choose an empty app